# Store MS Word .doc in database and then get it out again

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ms-word

To store the word doc in SQL I have this:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[uploader.UploadedFiles[0].InputStream.Length];
        var storedFile = new email_attachment();
        string strFullPath = uploader.UploadedFiles[0].FileName;
        string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFullPath);

        storedFile.email_attachment_id = Guid.NewGuid();
        storedFile.emailer_id = new Guid(dropMailers.SelectedValue);
        storedFile.file_name = strFileName;
        storedFile.file_data = bytes;
        db.email_attachments.InsertOnSubmit(storedFile);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

To get it back I use this:

```
 var storedFile = db.email_attachments.Where(a => a.email_attachment_id.ToString() == dropAttachments.SelectedValue).Single();

        string strPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Storage/Email/Attachments");

        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(strPath, storedFile.file_name), storedFile.file_data.ToArray());
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(Path.Combine(strPath, storedFile.file_name));

        if (file != null && file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {

            //Response.Write("This file does not exist.");

        }
```

Problems:  The doc I get back is blank, and I also believe saving it in the file system and then writing it to the response stream isn't very efficient.  I'm thinking that step could be skipped.  Any help or info would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question has more to do with LINQ and a database than with SQL.

Comment: Shouldn't the content type be **application/msword**?

Comment: Tried application/msword and it didn't work.  if I have the file stored somewhere on the hard drive - application/octet-stream works fine in opening at as a word doc (with the doc's content intact).

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this code to start with:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[uploader.UploadedFiles[0].InputStream.Length];
var storedFile = new email_attachment();
string strFullPath = uploader.UploadedFiles[0].FileName;
string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFullPath);

storedFile.email_attachment_id = Guid.NewGuid();
storedFile.emailer_id = new Guid(dropMailers.SelectedValue);
storedFile.file_name = strFileName;
storedFile.file_data = bytes;
db.email_attachments.InsertOnSubmit(storedFile);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I can see you creating an empty array - but I can't see where you're populating it anywhere. Shouldn't you be reading from the `InputStream` instead of just finding out its length?

(You may well want to copy from the input stream into a `MemoryStream`, and then use `ToArray` to get a byte array out at the end. There's plenty of sample code around for copying a stream - and in .NET 4 there's even the `WriteTo` method which makes it easier.)

I haven't even looked at the later code yet - first let's make sure you actually get some data into the database first...

Comment: I'm not having any luck finding any resources or sample code.

Comment: @FiveTools: Which bit are you having problems with? Copying an existing stream into a MemoryStream?

Comment: Thanks for giving me a heads up on the first part of the code.  I searched and I found some working code.  I was able to figure out what steps I was missing.  Posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

To write to the db:

```
                byte[] bytes = new byte[uploader.UploadedFiles[0].InputStream.Length];
                uploader.UploadedFiles[0].InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                var storedFile = new document();
                string strFullPath = uploader.UploadedFiles[0].FileName;
                string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFullPath);

                storedFile.document_id = Guid.NewGuid();
                storedFile.content_type = uploader.UploadedFiles[0].ContentType;
                storedFile.original_name = strFileName;
                storedFile.file_data = bytes;
                storedFile.date_created = DateTime.Now;
                db.documents.InsertOnSubmit(storedFile);
                db.SubmitChanges();
```

And to get the document back out:

```
var storedFile = db.documents.Where(a => a.document_id.ToString() == dropAttachments.SelectedValue).Single();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + storedFile.original_name + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite(storedFile.file_data.ToArray());
            Response.End();
```

Found my answer here: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/414/storing-uploaded-files-in-a-database-or-in-the-file-system-with-aspnet-20#Downloads

Comment: Reading from a stream in a single call to Read is very dangerous. You're *assuming* all the data will be made available immediately, which isn't always the case. You should always loop round, reading until there's no more data.

Comment: How would I make this method 'less dangerous?' - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155844/how-do-i-safely-read-from-a-stream-in-asp-net