# reading file binary received of fileUpload control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload, controls

I m looking for an code example as read file binary received of fileUpload control.

HTML

```
<form id="f" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server"  />
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Go" />
</p>
</form>
```

C# code(not working)

```
Stream FileContent = FileUpload.FileContent;
int size = Int32.Parse(Request.Headers["Content-Length"]);
byte[] buffer = new Byte[size];
FileContent.Read(buffer, 0, size);
string bin = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
FileContent.Close();
Response.Write(bin); //output 0???
```

Any help would be appreciated. and feel free to suggest a completely different way of solving the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

[How do I safely read from a stream in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155844/how-do-i-safely-read-from-a-stream-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something obvious here, but why not just use the [FileUpload.SaveAs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) on the FileUpload control to save the file locally?